# How can I make people can click a image and copy the related codes in my GIthubPage?

Tags: javascript, github-pages

Click a image, and pup out a box to copy the related code?

Wolfram's reference website has this feature,  how can I implement that into my Github page? or some similar things? (a  JS code?)

Any present people's page, theme?

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html

[image]

Comment: Long step... create a popup first, we can use `<div>`. Hidden, but ready to display with javascript function that you have to use a parameter too for the text what will you display. Finally, something like `<img src="image.png" onclick="show_popup('this is the related code')" />`

Comment: @AldiUnanto Are there any detailed references or similar questions? I think this maybe a general and duplicate question. Are there some tools for stupid man like me?

Answer (score 1):

**You can see the result of my description [here](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/6460348/)**

This effect my be achieved completely without javascript, keeping the code really simple.

We have to wrap the image and the code in a container, so that we know which one goes where. I'd suggest a `<figure>` element, as those are [thought](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/)for exactly this reason. We can then wrap our code example, explanation and whatnot in a nice `<figcaption>` element.

I'd say a code example should be in a `<textarea>`, as there it's already preformatted, has monospaced font and most importantly can be completely selected for copying with `strg`+`a`

So we have the following structure:

```
<figure>
    <img />
    <figcaption>
        <textarea />
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

We can then hide the `<figcaption>`, with CSS so by default it's not visible

```
figure figcaption {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, how do we make it visible? There is a neat, very underused feature called [`tabindex`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/button/tabindex), wich allows us to make single html elements "focussable", either by keyboard or by mouse. By setting a tabindex of 0, the element would be insert in the normal tab flow of the page. By setting the tabindex to -1, the item is clickable, but not focussable by keyboard.

So we set a tabindex of -1 on all figure elements:

```
<figure tabindex="-1">
</figure>
```

And now, by clicking on the image, you give the entire figure element focus. We can use this to show the box with CSS:

```
figure:focus figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```

This is already nearly what we want, only as soon as we click into the `<textarea>`, it gets focus, and it disappears again, as only one item at a time can be focussed on a page.

Thus we can add the following piece of CSS, which keeps on showing us the figcaption when we hover it:

```
figure figcaption:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

By default, focussed elements get a outline in some browsers. This my be somehow ugly in your case, so we can turn it off globally with CSS:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Then you only have to style the items like you wish they would look, position them, and you're done.

I built a small [example](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/6460348/), where you can see the code in action. Just check it out. The images are just sample pictures from [Lorem Pixel](http://lorempixel.com/), the code samples are from the ruby homepage.

Here's the code for my example (with just a bit of styling so you can see an example for that too):

**HTML**

```
<figure class="codeImage" tabindex="-1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <figcaption>
        Some sample code, maybe with some explanation:
        <textarea>
# The Greeter class
class Greeter
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name.capitalize
  end

  def salute
    puts "Hello #{@name}!"
  end
end

# Create a new object
g = Greeter.new("world")

# Output "Hello World!"
g.salute
        </textarea>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="codeImage" tabindex="-1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <figcaption>
        Some other code smaple, maybe with some explaination:
        <textarea>
# Output "I love Ruby"
say = "I love Ruby"
puts say

# Output "I *LOVE* RUBY"
say['love'] = "*love*"
puts say.upcase

# Output "I *love* Ruby"
# five times
5.times { puts say }

# Create a new object
g = Greeter.new("world")

# Output "Hello World!"
g.salute
        </textarea>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Example for images with copyable code sample on click
 */
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

figure {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 440px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

figure figcaption {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0; 
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 440px;
    padding: 10px;
}

figure figcaption textarea {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

figure:focus figcaption {
    display: block;
}

figure figcaption:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do @HyperGroups. But just a sample, you can modify depending on your case. Especially the text what will you show. I suggest to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I use jquery dialog for popup. and a function for receive the parameter.

**HTML**

```
<div id="popup"></div> ....
```

**jQuery**

```
function show_popup(particular_id){....
```

**CSS**

```
img{ display: inline-b...
```

[Open this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/rvKPx/) to see the result.